# NetBeans: Mapping conflict. A Servlet registration exists with same mapping as the Jersey servlet application

Tags: java, netbeans-7

NetBeans 7.4 returns the following SEVERE error:

```
SEVERE:   Mapping conflict. A Servlet registration exists with same mapping as the Jersey servlet application, named DataResource, at the servlet mapping, /webresources/*. The Jersey servlet is not deployed.
```

However I can't find any double registration inside NetBeans, I searched for any file containing the text

```
@ApplicationPath("webresources")
```

inside the project and only found one for resource DataResource.

Even the string "webresources" is used only once for this Resource so I don't know where NetBeans finds this conflict!

Comment: I happen to get the same warnings as well but I suspect a Netbeans bug, Resources by the way work correctly anyway so I just ignored them

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and encountered the same problem. Not sure if its helpful but I removed and re-added the war exploded artifact from the project structure and it solved this issue. Perhaps that translates to something helpful in NetBeans, or maybe someone reading is using IntelliJ.